# Possible CRC-32 Checksum Reverse Engineer Crack

Tags: md5, sha, crc, crc32

I'm trying to change some data from an old `PS1` game save file but the data keeps getting corrupted even though I isolated the exact bit I wanted to change and made sure nothing else was altered.

I changed some data for every save file and here's the possible checksum constant I found.

```
8A B5 2E CC
BD E6 AE 3A
B7 88 25 21
61 EC 03 37
35 3E 6D 59
11 48 91 D0
77 4B B2 85
85 55 F7 B5
```

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: Try a backup of a save file, do something within the game to make a minimal change and make another save file. XOR the two savefiles to produce a third "save file" of mostly zeroes (in most cases this will also be a valid savefile), to see what the differences are, and where the CRC is stored. Not knowing if a CRC is a product of two "binary prime" numbers, you may have to go through 2 billion iterations to try every odd value as a possible CRC.

Comment: Continuing, if a date / time stamp is used, then just saving twice in a row quickly could end up with just a one byte difference.